# How to get state of a child component in react js ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Login Component` and `Input Components` :

```
class Login extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeInput = this.handleChangeInput.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        email_user: "LOL",
        password_user: "",
    };
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    //alert('A name was submitted: ');
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
}

handleChangeInput(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
}

render() {

    return (
       <Input size="L" type="email" name="email_user" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email_user} />
       <Input size="L" type="password" name="password_user" placeholder="Mot de passe" value={this.state.password_user} onChange={this.handleChangeInput} />        );
    }

}
```

My Input component returns some HTML like :

```
            <div className={classInput}>
                <span className="input__text">
                    <input type={this.props.type} name={this.props.name} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} defaultValue={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange} required />
                </span>
            </div>
```

My Input `state` is updated great by the `handleChange` inside the `Input Component`.

But these `state` are not visible by the `Login Component`. With or without `handleChangeInput`, the states in the`Login Component` are not saved.

**How the `Login Component` can access to the update `state` inside child component please?**

Comment: You should never read from another component's state. Communicate with props and callbacks instead.

Comment: Okay! So what the solution?

Comment: @Steffi The solution would be to pass a function as a prop to your child component. Then the child component would pass its state up to the parent using the passed function.

Comment: @SimpleJ Thank you, do you a JsFiddle to show me this?

Comment: not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, here, but there are two options, if you're asking what I think you're asking. first, lift the desired state into the login component (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - adjust and sync this state using callbacks. second, you can get a reference to the input field by using the `ref` attribute. `<input ref={(input) => { this.input = input;}}/>` will set the input field on the parent to a reference to the input. From there you can use it like a standard JS object.

Comment: Sure. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/mRNyxx?editors=1010). I should note that it's usually considered an anti-pattern store state and pass it up like this. You could probably remove the state from your `Input` component entirely and pass up change events to the `Login` component where the state will be held.

Comment: @TylerSebastian The Lifting State Up works great. I just try it. You can answer my question by an official answer to close the question ;-). But I have a last question. How does it work if I had a lot of inputs to sync. I'm fine for 2-3 inputs. But what if there are 20 inputs state or more ? Docs React JS create a new handle for each input... Very not optimize I think. Is there a solution ?

Comment: @SimpleJ Thanks ! Same solution as Tyler Sebastien. It works, but I have a last question. How does it work if I had a lot of inputs to sync. I'm fine for 2-3 inputs. But what if there are 20 inputs state or more ? Docs React JS create a new handle for each input... Very not optimize I think. Is there a solution ?

Comment: @Steffi I'm not sure if there's a suggested solution. I've been working on a project that has that exact issue, and I've been using more generic handlers. Here's an example codepen: http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/Qdebgj?editors=1010

Comment: @SimpleJ Oh yeah! That's really better with this generic handler. I dont really understand this syntax " () => ... " You can post your complete solution as answer of this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Steffi I'm don't think I should post it as an answer because my solution doesn't really match your question.